# java - Image fits and works with jar, but not when using a String[] array to store the image names

Tags: java, arrays, image, animation, jar

**Edit:
 It was helpful to load the images only once in the default constructor, everything works much faster now. The problem, however, has changed. I can't open the jar file anymore, and if I launch it from the console using** java -jar BounceTheSphinx.jar **I get this**

```
Exception in thread ''main'' java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!:
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read<Unknown Source>
at BounceBack.PanneauJeu.<init>(PanneauJeu.java:55)
at BounceBack.FenetreJeu.<init>(FenetreJeu.java:21)
at BounceBack.MainBounceBack.main(MainBounceBack.java:11)
```

**Line 55 from PanneauJeu.java is `fondArray[j] = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(imageArray[j]));` I looked on other posts, but I can't solve my problem with the solutions proposed. The thing is, I really use the same technique to load and display those images, those images exist, everything works in eclipse, yet the `fondArray` one always causes the problem, not the `fondPerdu`**

**I edited the code for you to see**

So I wrote in the comments ''WORKS'' and ''DOESN'T WORK'' so you can see where my problem is.

```
public class PanneauJeu extends JPanel
{
private int i = 0;//color counter
private int j = 0;//imageArray counter
private int k = 0;//imagePerdu counter

private String[] imageArray = {"/resources/Sphinx.png", "/resources/Sphinx2.png ", "/resources/Sphinx3.png", "/resources/Sphinx4.png", "/resources/Sphinx5.png", "/resources/Sphinx6.png", "/resources/Sphinx7.png", "/resources/Sphinx8.png"};//score

private String[] imagePerdu = {"/resources/Lose5.png", "/resources/Lose6.png", "/resources/Lose7.png", "/resources/Lose8.png", "/resources/Lose9.png", "/resources/Lose10.png", "/resources/Lose11.png", "/resources/Lose12.png", "/resources/Lose13.png"};//, "Lose10.png", "Loose11.png", "Loose12.png"};  
private Image fond;
private Image fondArray[] = new Image[imageArray.length];
private Image fondPerdu[] = new Image[imagePerdu.length];

public PanneauJeu()//default constructor
{           
        for(int j = 0; j < imageArray.length; j++)
        {
            //DOESN'T WORK
            try
            {
                fondArray[j] = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(imageArray[j]));
            }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }

        for(int k = 0; k < imagePerdu.length; k++)
        {   
            //WORKS
            try
            {
                fondPerdu[k] = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(imagePerdu[k]));
            }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what could possibly be wrong? Remember, everything works just fine in Eclipse.

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: Can you try to make a smaller, self-contained, example of what fails? Your current code is a bit erratically formatted and it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Is this better? I took away all unrelated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the issue is, but there's one likely candidate:

You're loading an image every time that you want to display it.

In the case of an animation, that means trying to constantly reload lots of images. This is a burden both in terms of I/O and CPU time. What you want to do is load your images once, and then keep them around (instead of just the file names) to display when you need them. This way, your program doesn't have to be constantly loading and reloading the same data from the filesystem.

There's a reasonable chance that you have another issue, but doing this should make it easier to find.

Once you've moved your loading to happen once, if the problem persists, try launching your JAR from the command line: run `java -jar <PATH TO JARFILE>`, and see if it prints out any errors. There's a good chance that there's an error happening then that you can't see if you try to launch the JAR from a GUI.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said and it works much faster now. But the jar doesn't open up anymore. I tried to launch it from the console, as you said. I edited my post for you to see.
Thanks again

Comment: Ok I got it! The problem was here:
"/resources/Sphinx2.png ".

There is a blank space a the end of the name! It should be like this:
"/resources/Sphinx2.png"

But anyway, I still find it weird that the program ran under Eclipse, but not as a jar. I'll be much more careful about this in the future:

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @NicoKm The `getResource` method will return null if the resource doesn't exist, so that's why it was crashing like it did. The difference between Eclipse and a JAR would probably be that Eclipse runs on a filesystem and a JAR isn't exactly one - there's a good chance that something involved in talking with the filesystem is willing to strip off an extra space, while JARs require a bit more specificity.